# Uploading file chunks using socket.io/node.js not working with non-text files

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

Just messing around with node.js, I am trying to get a file uploader working that chunks the file on the client side, sends pieces to the server via socket.io, and reassembles. It's a rather naive implementation, but just trying to learn. Currently if I submit a text file, it moves over and is reassembled correctly, but if I try to upload say an image file, the encoding is messed up and the file is corrupt.

I am reading on the client side as binary string, and the node fs encoding is set to binary. What else needs to happen?

**Client Code**

```
while(start < fileSize)
{
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(e){
        var data = {
            "data" : e.target.result,
            "sequence" : chunkCount++
        };
        socket.emit("sendChunk", data, function(data){
            console.log("Confirmation recieved");
        });
        console.log("Log: Sent");
    };

    reader.onerror = function(e){
        alert(e.getMessage());
    };

    var blob = file.slice(start, end);
    reader.readAsBinaryString(blob);
    start = end;
    end = end + chunkSize;

}
```

**Server Code**

```
socket.on('sendChunk', function (data) {
    fs.appendFileSync(path + fileName, data.data, 'binary');
    console.log(data.sequence + ' - The data was appended to file ' + fileName);
});
```

## **Update**

With the suggestion given, I updated the code to use base64 decoding. There is still some sequencing issues going on sometimes, but for the most part files are transferring correctly.

**Client Code:**

```
var data = {
    "data" : window.btoa(e.target.result),
    "sequence" : chunkCount++
};
socket.emit("sendChunk", data, function(data){
    console.log("Confirmation recieved");
});
```

**Server Code:**

```
var decoded =  new Buffer(data.data, 'base64').toString('binary');
fs.appendFileSync(path + fileName, decoded, 'binary');
```

Comment: I'm not 100% sure here, but if I had to guess, your `onload` callbacks are probably running out of order. Your `sequence` number right now could be misleading because you increment it inside of `onload` so you  increment when the value is sent, not when the result is start/end are calculated.

Comment: I hadn't thought of that. With a text file it seems to to do everything in the right order, but I understand that that's not guaranteed. Another odd issue is that with the image files, the copied file is typically much larger than the original, which is what led me to assume it was something with encoding.

Comment: It's larger because certain bytes in the image payload are being interpreted as control characters, and thus escaped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`socket.emit()` is written in JavaScript and thus treats the payload as a JavaScript `String`. You are receiving garbled data on the server because in JavaScript strings are represented in UCS-2, and certain control characters are being escaped. In other words: a JavaScript string is not an `Array` of byte-sized characters, and it's not suitable for storing or transporting binary data.

The safest way to transmit your image is to [encode the binary data as base64](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.btoa) on the client, and decode on the server with [the Buffer class](http://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buf_tostring_encoding_start_end).